# How do I add Persistent Menu to my Facebook Bot using C# Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

I've created a bot using Microsoft's .NET Bot framework. I don't find a way to add persistent menu to my bot. How do I add that ?

Answer (score 4):

To create a persistent menu on Facebook you need to make an API call with the menu items and postback payload:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"setting_type" : "call_to_actions","thread_state" : "existing_thread","call_to_actions":[{"type":"postback","title":"TITLE1","payload":"action?action1"}, {"type":"postback","title":"TITLE2","payload":"action?action2"},{"type":"postback","title":"TITLE3","payload":"action?action3"}]}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token={YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}"
```

You can remove it similarly:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"setting_type":"call_to_actions","thread_state":"existing_thread"}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token={YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}"
```

Comment: I got a success response. However, even after ~12 hrs, the persistent menu doesn't show up. Any ideas ?

Comment: Which client are you using?  Persistent menus will only show up in the Messenger client, not if you are using the chat window from Facebook

Comment: I've checked the Messenger client on both my Smartphone as well as web. The way I test my bot is using my personal facebook account and I try to chat with the bot. 
Curious, if an account A has already initiated the conversation with the bot, will that account A see this persistent menu ?  Note: I even restarted my phone, restarted my browser etc.. (in case something is cached...)

Comment: statuscode: 200, {"result": "Successfully added structured menu CTAs"}

Comment: Another StackOverflow user says it took > 24 hrs for some 'cache' to clear (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801639/facebook-messenger-api-persistent-menu-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: Even after > 24 hours, I still don't see it :(

Comment: @rajkiran - There is a special note in the Facebook developer docs that says "You must set up a Get Started button if you also wish to use persistent menu.". Is it possible your persistent menu setup is good but you are missing a get started button?